# modifying Postfix message content

Tags: postfix

I am using postfix mail server and i need to replace mail content inside every incoming and outgoing message based on some predefined rules.

What is needed is to filter remote and local mail to replace every instance of **user@domain.com** in header or body with **user@blah.com**

header_checks and body_checks options seem cumbersome, maybe there is better/faster option that works on whole message instead going line by line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix support header address rewriting at outgoing mail:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic_map
```

**/etc/postfix/generic_map**

```
user@example.com    user@example.org

# postmap /etc/postfix/generic_map
```

Using regular expression:

```
smtp_generic_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/generic_map.regexp
```

**/etc/postfix/generic_map**

```
(.*?)@example.com    $1@example.org
```

Isn't supported change in body. You need create you own content filter.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_generic_maps

Answer (score 1):

You should look at content filters, as mentioned in [Postfix's documentation](http://www.postfix.org/documentation.html).

You probably want to use a before-queue content filter. This can probably be written fairly easily in something like Perl or Python. The Postfix guide for before-queue filters also links to a program called [smtpprox](http://bent.latency.net/smtpprox/) which you might be able to repurpose for your needs.